# Roles and Permissions issue from OneDrive API/SDK

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, onedrive

I am trying to use OneDrive API/SDK to retrieve permissions of Shared with Me items in OneDrive for Business. Some of the files/folders have read only permission while others have read/write both. I observe that for resources having read only permission, I am getting "roles" field as empty after below call(s):

```
var preference = await client.Drives[driveId].Items[itemID].Permissions.Request().GetAsync();

GET:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/driveId/items/itemID/permissions
```

Where as for the files/folders having read/write access, I am getting "roles" field with one item as "write". My expectation is for read only items, I should get "roles" field data as "read" as per [this link](https://dev.onedrive.com/resources/permission.htm#roles-enumeration).

Please suggest if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Saket for reporting this issue. It is indeed a bug in the api. We are working to fix it.

Comment: Hey Saket, this issue should now be fixed. Please let me know if you see otherwise.